yt_dlp downloading video with no audio
The code used to work flawlessly a few months ago. Now, videos are downloaded with no audio. Any thoughts on maybe options that should be updated?

import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
    
filename = "https://youtu.be/VIDEO_LINK"
    
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'mp4',
    'outtmpl' : filename[17:]+'.%(ext)s'
}
    
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:ydl.download([filename])



Mostly this is because youtube updated its method of delivery of audio,video tracks,you must post this as issue to library.

If you're not using the latest version of yt-dlp, then please update and check again. If it still doesn't work, please say so and indicate the version you used. If you haven't updated in several months, there are good chances that it won't work, as YouTube makes frequent updates that break it.

Prior to 12/23/24 the script was not working. I checked the GitHub repo and I was using the latest rev. Turns out, they  released an update shortly after. I upgraded and now works. Thanks for the reminder.

Upgraded to the latest version of yt_dlp.
